# About making a vb6 application that can run on Android

Tags: android, vb.net

Sir, I am a vb programmer. I want to develope a vb application that can be run on an android phone or tablet. What I should do for that and how can i install this application on android phone or tablet and run it successfully? Generally i use ms access or sql server for my desktop application. Which data base should i use with my vb application on android phone or tablet?

Comment: I would be so surprised if this is possible my heart may actually stop.

Answer (score 2):

Someone has pointed out [Google's Simple project](http://code.google.com/p/simple/) which compiles VB to Android...

May god have mercy on our souls...

**EDIT:** Link Changed to actual project.

Answer (score 1):

If [MonoDroid](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid?gclid=COH6wa_Y3q0CFYsntAod0jm-fg) ever supports VB.Net that will probably be your best bet. It doesn't at the moment though, and there is no time frame for this happening..

Your best bet is to learn Java and use the android development Kit or learn C# and use MonoDroid.

As for DB Android has SQL Lite built into it, so I'd recommend using that.

Comment: Thank for ur response but recently i read that google has released vb compiler for android- what does it mean? Sorry I know much about vb programming but nothing about other.

Comment: Also if you know much about VB programming you should be able to pick up any language, it's all if statements and loops just with slightly different syntax. Just need to pick up OO principles.

Answer (score 1):

There is a thing called B4A (Basic for Android) and (B4I) (basic for IOS)

You can run the basic Ide B4A comes with, while not 100% VB6 it is very close and should be able to write a program eaisly.

When it compiles, it does so to Java and you end up with an APK file which you can copy to the android device and install from there.

See link [www.B4x.com](https://www.b4x.com/b4a.html#:%7E:text=B4A-Bridge%20%28recommended%29%201%20B4A-Bridge%20allows%20the%20IDE%20to,are%20ready%20to%20run%20your%20first%20Android%20program%21)

> B4A includes all the features needed to quickly develop any type of Android app.
> B4A is used by tens of thousands of developers from all over the world, including companies such as NASA, HP, IBM and others.
> Together with B4i you can easily develop applications for both Android and iOS.

Essentially you need

1. Oracle Java 8 or OpenJDK 11/14 (recommended)
2. Android SDK + Required Resources
3. B4A
4. B4A-Bridge